# Importing my own classes into Android studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I was just wondering if anyone knows how import "homemade" classes from eclipse into android studio. I have some java classes that I wrote in eclipse and I'd like to import into android studio(the eclipse classes DO HAVE DEPENDENCIES). This may seem like a silly question given the fact I've only been using android studio for few days now

Comment: copy/paste should do it, assuming they don't have third party/unavailable dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If it is single classes, you can just copy-paste the code or files themselves. The classes are the same in either IDE.

If there are any specific dependencies that are required, those have to be added for the file to compile. Using Gradle you can find mostly any dependencies there. Some aren't available through gradle though, those have to be added manually as .jars. Gradle still needs to add the jars to the list of dependencies though.

If the files are made in plain java (meaning not android platform tools) you can most likely not import them (based on your comment). Android has a separate SQLite system, you don't need dependencies for it. And in most cases, non-android dependencies don't work on Android because they require desktop tools and a desktop environment to work

Comment: Copy-paste works either way. It's a compile that will fail if there are missing dependencies

Comment: You would assume that they would want it to compile no, or throw no missing deps errors in the ide, I'd say importing suggests this? But you've amended answer to say exactly what I said anyway?

Comment: You wrote that comment as a reply to the contents of the answer which at the time was about copy-pasting. Your comment basically said copy-paste works assuming all the dependencies are there. I replied to that. Of course the files are supposed to be compiled, but your original message basically referred to the copy-paste. Or that's how I understood it at least.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't figure out how to reply to your comment I just got this app haha. I appreciate your feedback it definitely helps, do you have any further knowledge on how I would go about connecting my project to my MySQL database?

Comment: It's all documented, just check the docs and you can find the answer to that there